# How to use regex to match two works in a line

Tags: java, regex

I have a line:

user1 home1

I can use `"(.*?) "` to match user1, but failed to use `" (.*?)$"` to match home1.

How to match them? I cannot use split. Have to use regex to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should also work:

```
String str = "user1 home1";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\s+(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pt.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Group1: [" + matcher.group(1) + "] Group2: [" + matcher.group(2) + ']');
}
```

Catch everything in first capture group until 1 or more spaces `\\s+` are found and after that put everything in second capture group.

#### OUTPUT

```
Group1: [user1] Group2: [home1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `.?` to match user1.  That matches 0 or 1 characters.

You want:  `(\S+)\s+(\S+)`

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will match both words:

```
^(\w+)\s+(\w+)$
```

The Pattern explained:

```
^        Begin of Line
(\w+)    One or more word characters (letters and digits), stored in group $1
\s+      Whitespace, one or more chars
(\w+)    One or more word characters (letters and digits), stored in group $2
$        End of Line
```

Also, `.*?` is probably not what you need, as it can easily match the empty String. When you have a fixed Structure, you'll want greedy matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick `"\\w+"`
 no need to use grouping as a few suggested.
And you get your Java
`while (matcher.find())` loop.